# Kafka event Producer on RDBMS data & reading it at consumer in same order of producer in case of multiple topics

Tags: apache-kafka, event-handling, kafka-consumer-api, confluent-platform, azure-eventhub

I have two business entities in RDBMS: Associate & AssociateServingStore. I planned to have two topics currently writing ADD/UPDATE/DELETE into AssociateTopic & AssociateServingStoreTopic, and these two topics are consumed by several downstream systems which would use for their own business needs.

Whenever an Associate/AssociateServingStore is added from UI, currently I have Associate & AssociateServingStore writing into two separate topics, and I have a single consumer at my end to read both topics, the problem is order of messages that can be read from two separate topics.. as this follows a workflow I cannot read AssociateServingStore without reading Associate first.. how do I read them in order ? (with partition key I can read data in order for same topic within partition) but here I have two separate topics and want to read in an order, first read Associate & then AssociateServingSotre and How to design it in such a way that I can read Associate before AssociateServingStore.

If I thinking as a consumer myself, I am planning to read first 50 rows of Associate and then 50 rows from AssocateServingStore and process the messages, but the problem is if I get a row in AssociateServingStore from the 50 records that are consumed which is not in already read/processed from first 50 Associate events, I will get issues on my end saying parent record not found while child insert.

**How to design consumer in these cases of RDBMS business events where we have multiple topics but read them in order so that I will not fall in a situation where I might read particular child topic message before reading parent topic message and get issues during insert/update like parent record not found. Is there a way we can stage the data in a staging table and process them accordingly with timestamp ? I couldn't think of design which would guarantee the read order and process them accordingly**

Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 1):

This seems like a streaming join use-case, supported by some stream-processing frameworks/libraries.

For instance, with Kafka Streams or ksqlDB you can treat these topics as either tables or streams, and apply joins between tables, streams, or stream to table joins.

These joins handle all the considerations related to streams that do not happen on traditional databases, like how long to wait when time on one of the streams is more recent than the other one[1][2].

This presentation[3] goes into the details of how joins work on both Kafka Streams and ksqlDB.

[1] https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/KIP-353%3A+Improve+Kafka+Streams+Timestamp+Synchronization
[2] https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/KIP-695%3A+Further+Improve+Kafka+Streams+Timestamp+Synchronization
[3] https://www.confluent.io/events/kafka-summit-europe-2021/temporal-joins-in-kafka-streams-and-ksqldb/